# Static Page translation in Yii

Tags: php, internationalization, yii

I have this small problem with Yii's static pages. I can't translate static pages on fly using i18n, or I just fell on a pit that translating static pages are really not possible?. I know how to use i18n now but I was able to translate pages only non static pages(pages with controllers)

Thanks for any reply

Comment: What do you mean by "static pages" - actions loaded with `CViewAction`? How are doing translations, and how are you storing the translated text? Can't you just wrap the text in your "static" view files with `Yii::t()`? You can still execute PHP in the "static" pages that are loaded by `CViewAction`.

Comment: yes, actions loaded with CViewAction... can you give me a sample code? thanks

Comment: I would still need to know how you are doing the translations and storing the alternate language data to be able to help you, sorry. It's always good to include as much information as you can in SO question. You can edit the question to add more information. Assuming you have your i18n configured, you will probably want to use View File translation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n#file-translation

Comment: I've tried this one... its already working http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29344-changing-language-in-static-pages/page__p__141255#entry141255 thanks

Comment: Ah, so `CViewAction` calls `findLocalizedFile()`, meaning it _does_ do the "View File" translation I mentioned. Nice. Thanks for the update, glad you found your answer. Feel free to add the answer to your question here on SO (with a link to the Yii forum) so this question does not appear "unanswered". Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this one and it works [Static Page translation](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29344-changing-language-in-static-pages/page__p__141255#entry141255)